iOS Error Code=256 in try read file from local filesystem
I have a problem when trying to open the file and read it. Im giving Error: "Code=256 cannot open file test.csv"
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let docURL = URL(string: documentsDirectory)!
let dataPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myDir/\(fileName)")
do {
    let content = try String(contentsOf: dataPath, encoding: .utf8)
    print(content)         
} catch {
    print(error)
}

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, saving the file as above is ok. Of course when I check the path in the terminal it is fine. File exist.

It is very likely an invalid URL. The status code indicates NSFileReadUnknownError, which is not at all useful. You can probably fix it by using a different URL initializer.
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let docURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory) // <-- This line
let dataPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myDir").appendingPathComponent(fileName)

do {
    let content = try String(contentsOf: dataPath, encoding: .utf8)
    print(content)
} catch {
    print("Failed to read file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

